# Distance in conformal field theoy

Tags: conformal-field-theory

I am learning CFT from Francesco's book and I am quite confused about the notion of distance bewteen two points in CFT. In page 104, When determining the possible form of 2-point correlation function, the book mentioned that Poincare symmetry ensures that 2pt function only depends on the distance between two points:
$<\phi_1(x_1)\phi_2(x_2)>=f(|x_1-x_2|)$.
I suppose that the distance here is just the inner product with the Minkwoski metric:
$\eta_{\mu\nu}(x_1-x_2)^\mu(x_1-x_2)^\nu$
which seems natural to me. Later in the book, the 2pt function transforms under special conformal transformation (SCT), but this time, the distance $|x^\prime_1-x^\prime_2|$ seems confusing because the new metric $\eta^{\prime}_{\mu\nu}$ depends on coordinates. To see that the metric in the new coordinate system indeed depends on coordinates, we can substitute (4.52), (4.33) into (4.1) and we see that the new metric is conformally flat but depends on coordinates.

So my question is how do we define the distance in the coordinates after SCT? I came across this question when trying to prove (4.22), can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

First, the metric in di Francesco's book is $\delta_{\mu\nu}$ before you act with conformal transformations. CFT in Minkowski signature is very interesting but it's a richer subject due to the possibility of multi-valued correlation functions.

Second, the metric in di Francesco's book is also $\delta_{\mu\nu}$ *after* you act with conformal transformations. To find out what these are, we solve the Killing equation for co-ordinate changes which locally rescale the metric but do not affect other operators. *I.e.* they are passive transformations. This is merely a preparatory step for the final goal which is to change viewpoints, declare the metric to be fixed once and for all, and implement the conformal group as *active* transformations which affect the states.

Comment: Thank you for answering!